# How can i implement spherical hankel function of the first kind by scipy/numpy or sympy?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sympy

I knew that there is no builtin sph_hankel1 in scipy then i want to know that how to implement it in the right way?

Additional: Just show me one correct implementation of sph_hankel1 either using of Scipy or Sympy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding implementing it in SymPy, there is a guide on how to implement special functions [here](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/wiki/About-implementing-special-functions). We would love pull requests for well-known special functions.

For numerical routines, they are implemented in [mpmath](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/mpmath/functions/bessel.html#hankel-functions). It [looks like](https://github.com/fredrik-johansson/mpmath/blob/master/mpmath/functions/bessel.py#L176) it just uses the definition directly.

Comment: Thank you a lot sir @asmeurer, IMO i think any builtin functions that Mathematica have Scipy/Numpy or Sympy should have also. It may be easy to implement it but the hard part is to verify that my implementation is correct or not that a little bit take my time.

Comment: The wolfram functions site is a good source of identities and such. For correctness, the easiest way is to do random numerical testing against a known numerical routine (usually for SymPy this is mpmath).

Answer (score 3):

Although it would be nice if there were an existing routine for calculating the spherical Hankel functions (like there is for the ordinary Hankel functions), they are just a (complex) linear combination of the spherical Bessel functions of the first and second kind so can be easily calculated from existing routines.  Since the Hankel functions are complex and depending on your application of them, it can be advantageous to rewrite your expression in terms of the Bessel functions of the first and second kind, ie entirely real quantities, particularly if your final result is real.

Comment: There is a good scipy specific review of how these fit together here: http://www.johndcook.com/Bessel_python.html  and here: http://www.johndcook.com/Bessel_functions.html

Comment: One should also consider numerical stability. Often computing special functions from some mathematical formula is a bad idea because it ends up being numerically unstable.

Comment: I guess in this case it is fine. See [how mpmath does it](https://github.com/fredrik-johansson/mpmath/blob/master/mpmath/functions/bessel.py#L176).